# Downloading and storing locally on tvOS

Tags: swift, file, video, storage, tvos

I’m struggling to find any good docs/tutorials on this topic as generally TVOS development isn’t so popular and because my use case is a little niche so the questions I’m about to ask might be a bit silly but here goes:

I’m trying to build an app that will essentially be a video player (will actually be a mix of file types eventually but starting with video) that lets you navigate back and forth through videos like a slide deck.

I need to be able to download the videos and store them on the Apple TV as the actual device will be taken to my different clients’ locations and there may be no internet connection there.

The device won’t be used to install any other apps so I’m not worried about there not being enough space or TVOS clearing out downloaded files automatically to make space. I just want to know where I’m supposed to save files to!

Is there a temporary files folder or do I need to create a database or can I use coreData in some way?

Thanks,

Elliot

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/iCloudStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH10-SW1

Comment: On tvOS, you need to save files to `NSCachesDirectory`

Comment: It can also be one of _FileManager.SearchPathDirectory_ enums like `.applicationSupportDirectory` or `.downloadsDirectory`